# How to reject multiple requests on button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have a button if I press it multiple times it sends the request. How can I achieve it to block all requests after 1 initial request is successful?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use a state variable and set it to true on click of the button. And disable the button if the state value is true. Once you get the response back from the API you change the state value back to false. Now the button is enabled since the state value is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the disabled attribute of button to disable once the request starts to send and then you can enable it once data received if you want.

like:

```
function sendRequest() {
 // disable the button on start of this function

 // request code operations

 // enable the button here
}
```